# How do I import newsletter subscribers into M2?

Tags: magento2, import, newsletter

Can anyone tell me the php code to import Newsletter subscribers into M2? I have thousands of subscribers I'd like to import but don't know enough php to do it without a guide.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code to any file and put that file in magento root

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$email = 'test@gmail.com';
$status = $obj->get('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber')->subscribe($email);

?>
```

You need to add code according to your csv.